# Extract a particular args value from Kubernetes Deployment object

Tags: shell, sh

I have the Kubernetes deployment object args displayed as below

```
kubectl get  deploy external-dns --output=jsonpath='{.spec.template.spec.containers[0].args}'
```

Output:

```
[--log-level=info --log-format=text --policy=sync --provider=aws --registry=txt --interval=1m --txt-owner-id=us-west-2:testcluster --source=service --source=ingress --aws-batch-change-size=1000]%
```

I want to extract only this field --txt-owner-id=us-west-2:testcluster  value..

The output I am expecting is (the value of that field),

```
us-west-2:testcluster
```

I am not sure if using sed or awk helps..Or if we have jsonpath itself for it.Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

1: the simple way use  awk and sed you can try this

```
kubectl get  deploy external-dns --output=jsonpath='{.spec.template.spec.containers[0].args}'  |awk -F"=" '{print $8}'|sed 's/--source//'
```

2: use grep:

```
kubectl get  deploy external-dns --output=jsonpath='{.spec.template.spec.containers[0].args}'|grep -oE  '\-\-txt-owner-id=(.*\:\w+){1}[[:space:]]'|sed 's/ //g'|awk -F"=" '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou..I am not sure if print $8 is always txt-owner-id..

Your answer gave me this idea..

this works too..

```
kubectl get  deploy external-dns -n add-ons  --output=jsonpath='{.spec.template.spec.containers[0].args}' |awk -F"txt-owner-id=" '{print $2}'| cut -d " " -f1
```